# Mutable vs Lazy Evaluation

Tags: c++, constants, lazy-evaluation, mutable

Recently I was reading [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#logical-vs-physical-state) faq on const-correctness. Now I came across the following situation where I dont know what to make const or mutable.
Assume the simple example:

```
class Averager {
public:
    Averager() : sum(0),isUptoDate(false),N(0){}
    void add(double x){
        sum+=x;
        N+=1;
        isUptoDate = false;
    }
    double getAverage() const {
        if (!isUptoDate){updateAverage();}
        return average;
    }
private:
    void updateAverage(){
        if(N>0){average = sum / N;}
        else   {average = 0;}
        isUptoDate = true;
    }    
    double sum;
    mutable bool isUptoDate;
    int N;
    double average;
};
```

In the real case, `updateAverage()` is an expensive calculation, thus I want to avoid updating each time a value is added. Also, `getAverage()` might be called several times, before a new value is added, thus I want to update only if really necessary. On the other hand, it should not be the responsibility of the user of the class to call `updateAverage()`, thus I used the flag to know whether an update has to be made or not.

As I understood, `getAverage()` should clearly be a const method while `isUptoDate` can be mutable (its not part of the logical state but just a private implementation detail). However, `updateAverage()` is definitely not const and I cannot call it from within a const method.

What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks fine to me, you just need to make your `average` also mutable, because it'll be lazily computed by `getAverage`. `updateAverage` should also be `const`, because it will be called by `getAverage`. Since `updateAverage` is private, its own existence is an implementation detail. It's called only once, you could as well inline it into `getAverage`:

```
double getAverage() const {
    if (!isUptoDate){
        if(N>0){average = sum / N;}
        else   {average = 0;}
        isUptoDate = true;
    }
    return average;
}
```

Indeed, I **really** suggest you inline it, because it makes no sense to have it in the header file (you have to recompile all the users if you change its signature or its const-ness). If it's not just 3 lines in the real case, you can have it as a lambda, if you use C++11:

```
double getAverage() const {
    auto updateAverage=[&]{
        if(N>0){average = sum / N;}
        else   {average = 0;}
        isUptoDate = true;
    };
    if (!isUptoDate){ updateAverage(); }
    return average;
}
```

Comment: actually I had this in mind as a fix and I just wanted to edit the question to mention it. But somehow I had the feeling that it is bad (or "evil") to do so. Thanks for giving good reasoning why it is indeed ok.

Comment: Also, beware of numerical problems. Lazy evaluation will bring significance issues, because you usually end up adding numbers on the same scale to a sum which gets bigger and bigger. Consider using a compensation algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm

Comment: Also, note that the class goes against the thread safety default assumption (const members are safe to use concurrently), because `getAverage` writes something. This is fine, but it's a really good idea to document it. Alternatively, you can make it thread safe.

Comment: @SebastianRedl is this default assumption stated somewhere?

Comment: @SebastianRedl I dont know much about concurrency, but isnt this a general problem with mutables? What do you mean by "Alternatively, you can make it thread safe"?

Comment: @GiulioFranco I believe Herb Sutter formalized the idea. He quotes the standard paragraph the idea is based on: 17.6.5.9, which effectively states that the library will assume this behavior from user objects. http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/24/gotw-6a-const-correctness-part-1-3/

Comment: @tobi303 you'd need to use some synchronization mechanism to make your class thread-safe. But this is unnecessary. Unless you really need it to be threadsafe, just write a `//Not thread-safe` comment on the class and sleep unworried.

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, of course it's a general problem with mutables. But mutables are rare. The simplest way to make it thread-safe is to lock a mutex on every access to `average` (including reading, which may be slow, which is why more tricky schemes might be worthwhile).

Comment: @SebastianRedl Sutter's statement applies to "const on a variable that is possibly shared". So nothing new under the sky. You just say an object is not thread-safe, which means it cannot be shared. The only way to make this thing threadsafe would be to serialize all accesses to it. This is not how you do it. If you want multithread average, you should keep one sum per thread, and only collect them to compute the average. Indeed, I don't think it makes much sense to have a sequentially consistent multithread average.

Comment: @GiulioFranco I agree. But I still think that the lack of thread safety should be documented.

Comment: @SebastianRedl on that we agree.